# Getting code colored with emma in Android project

Tags: android, code-coverage, emma

I have code coverage with Emma for my Android projects and I get a nice html-file. But i kind of think an html-file isn't really good enough. I want to see covered and not covered code in the editor.

Is there a way to use the .em or .ec files are genereated to get Eclipse to color the code?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 1):

[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) the eclipse plugin gives you colored code coverage.

You just run your tests using this button: [image: EclEmma Run Tests]

And you get in Eclipse output like this:

[image]

Oh and I run my unit tests with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) that is Android but doesn't use Dalvik, uses your native JVM

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this what you are looking for [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), however it looks like it is now using JaCoCo for code coverage metrics rather than Emma perhaps there is an older version of the plug-in that still works.

I suppose it depends on what you want code coverage from Emma, or visualization in Eclipse.

Try comparing the outputs of JaCoCo and Emma, I would have thought they should give similar if not identical results, and then choose.

Does JaCoCo work against the android platform - I can't say.

Comment: From JaCoCo's implementation document http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/implementation.html, it doesn't support off-line instrumentation, which means the instrumentation can't be converted to Dalvik, which means it won't run on Android. It's possible that EclEmma retains the ability to display Emma-based coverage: perhaps its xml format is compatible?

Comment: Now that jaococo [supports offline instrumentation](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/64#issuecomment-12150910), how would it be possible to use it to generate coverage during test execution on android ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the ECLEmma team, on http://www.eclemma.org/devdoc/eclemma20.html:

> Future support for EMMA and EclEmma 1.x Maintenance
>
> From EclEmma 2.0 on EMMA will not be supported any more as a coverage
>   engine. ...
>
> Beside this we will try to maintain the EMMA based 1.x stream on a
>   best effort base but with no functional enhancements planned. There
>   will be a separate download for the 1.x versions.

Per my comment below, ECLEmma 2.0 uses JaCoCo which is currently incompatible with Android due to not supporting off-line instrumentation that can be processed into Dalvik. To use Emma with Eclipse, you need ECLEmma 1.0, so see here: http://www.eclemma.org/installation1x.html